# Analyze solutions to a matrix 3x5 matrix with two parameters and find a unique solution

Tags: linear-algebra

I have the linear system (over $\mathbb{R}$) for which I need to find a unique solution:
$$\begin{cases}
4x+8y+7z+3cw = 3b \\
x+2y+2z+cw=b \\
2x+4y+2z+(c-1)w=b
\end{cases}$$
for which the corresponding matrix is:
$$\begin{bmatrix}
4&8&7&3c&3b \\
1&2&2&c&b \\
2&4&2&c-1&b
\end{bmatrix}
$$
After the following elementary operations:

$R_2 \to R_1; R_2 \to R_2-4R_1, R_3 \to R_3-2R1;R_3 \to R_3-2R_2; R_2 \to -R_2$

I managed to get to the reduced form:
$$\begin{bmatrix}
1&2&2&c&b \\
0&0&1&c&b \\
0&0&0&c-1&b
\end{bmatrix}
$$

At this point I can see which conditions need to hold for the matrix:

1) to not have any solution: $c=1, b \neq 0$

2) to have infinitely many solutions: $c=1, b=0$ or $c \neq 1, b=0$ or $c \neq 1, b \neq 0$

3) $\mathbf{However}$ I don't see any way how there'd be a unique solution to the system because we have more variables than equations and the column of $w$ variable cannot be a column of zeroes.

Comment: You are right. $y$ is a free variable which prevents this system from having a unique solution.

Comment: @PJK would it be correct to write the solution for the matrix if $c \neq 1$ like this: $y=t, w={b \over c-1}, z = -cw={c \over 1-c}, x = -2t - {2c \over 1-c} - {-cb \over c-1}$?

Comment: I would say $z=-cw+b$ and $x=-2t-2z-cw+b$.

Answer (score -1):

**So we have system of equations:**

$\begin{cases}
4x+8y+7z+3cw=3b
\\
x+2y+2z+cw=b
\\
2x+4y+2z+(c-1)w=b
\end{cases}$

**And the matrix of it is:**

$\begin{bmatrix}
4&8&7&3c&3b
\\
1&2&2&c&b
\\
2&4&2&c-1&b
\end{bmatrix}$

**Using these steps:**

$1)\,R1\rightleftharpoons R2$

$2)\,R2=R2-4R1$

$3)\,R3=R3-2R1$

$4)\,R1=R1+R2$

$5)\,R3=R3-2R2$

$6)\,R2=(-1)\times R2$

**I got:**

$\begin{bmatrix}
1&2&1&0&0
\\
0&0&1&c&b
\\
0&0&0&c-1&b
\end{bmatrix}$

$\Rightarrow\,
\begin{cases}
x+2y+z=0
\\
z+cw=b
\\
(c-1)w=b
\\
y\quad is\,free
\end{cases}$

**Then I started solving them:**

$1)\quad (c-1)w=b \\ \hspace{9mm}w=\frac{b}{c-1}$

$2)\quad z+cw=b \\
\hspace{9mm}z+c\times\frac{b}{c-1}=b \\
\hspace{9mm}z+\frac{cb}{c-1}=b \\
\hspace{9mm}z\times (c-1)+cb=b\times (c-1) \\
\hspace{9mm}z(c-1)+cb=cb-b \\
\hspace{9mm}z(c-1)=cb-b-cb \\
\hspace{9mm}z(c-1)=-b \\
\hspace{9mm}z=-\frac{b}{c-1} $

$3)\quad x+2y+z=0 \\
\hspace{9mm}x=-2y-z \\
\hspace{9mm}x=-2y-(-b) \\
\hspace{9mm}x=b-2y$

**So the unique solution is:**

$\begin{cases}
x=b-2y
\\
y=y
\\
z=-\frac{b}{c-1}
\\
w=\frac{b}{c-1}\hspace{18mm},\,c-1\neq 0
\end{cases}$

Comment: I'm pretty sure you have a mistake in transition 2: $z + {cb \over c-1}=b$ and then $z+cb = b(c-1$. And also you have one free variable in your solution so how is it a unique solution?

Comment: I don't think I have any mistake in the transition, since I have put every steps of it. And I would guess that if you put "$y=y$" and not "$y\,is free$" then it would make it unique (not sure).

Comment: @ RedRose: $z + {cb \over c-1}=b \Leftrightarrow (z+{cb \over c-1}) \cdot (c-1)=b \cdot (c-1)$ in your solution $z$ is not multiplied by $c-1$ while it should be. and again $y$ is free...

Comment: Oh, sorry my bad, just realized it. I will edit my answer.

Comment: @ RedRose: sorry I can't accept your answer because to the best of my knowledge and understanding if you have free variables unique solution is not possible. In your solution $y$ is a free variable.